# launch4j - How to make generated exe to look JRE in the same folder

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

I want my generated exe to look for jre in the same folder with exe (**Not Program Files/Java** etc). So when i create an installer for my application, it will extract jre to setup folder and my exe will use that

Is it possible?

Comment: Reading the doc here: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html have you tried setting the value of `<path>`to `.` or `.\jre`?

Comment: I think, without writing  slash symbol and writing  directly jre folder name is working now.